# Branch points and Branch cuts

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, branch-cuts, analytic-functions, branch-points

I am currently studying about Branch points and Branch cuts. I think, I understood the definition of these two concepts and I can find Branch points and Branch cuts of some functions.

For example:
$z\to\sqrt{z(1-z)}$ has two branch points $0$ and $1.$ Because as we travel along a small circle around $0$ or $1,$ one time, argument of the function changes to $0\to \pm\pi i.$
On the other hand, $z\to\sqrt{z}+\sqrt{1-z}$ has three branch points $0, 1$ and $\infty.$
(Correct me if I am wrong.)

Here my question is:

> There are identities which fails on some branches of logarithm.
>   Is there any way to determine the region for which these familiar identities valid using Branch points and Branch cuts?

For example: $$\color{Green}{\sqrt{z-1}\sqrt{z+1}=\sqrt{z^2-1}}$$ does hot holds for $z=-2,$ if we choose $\sqrt{-1}=i.$

Comment: If $ab \ne 0$ then $\log(ab) = \log(a)+\log(b)+2i k \pi$ for some $k \in \mathbb{Z}$ is always true for any branch of $\log(z)$. Changing of branch means changing $k$ (which depends in general on $a,b$)

Comment: Thank you @user1952009 Yes. I got your idea. But how can it helps to solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In [THIS ANSWER](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2145677/is-logz2-2-logz-if-textlogz-1-z-2-ne-textlogz-1-textlogz/2145780#2145780), I discussed the meaning of the identity

$$\log(z_1z_2)=\log(z_1)+\log(z_2) \tag 1$$

In that expression, the equality is interpreted as a set equality.  This means for any value of $\log(z_1z_2)$ can be expressed as the sum of some value of $\log(z_1)$ and some value of $\log(z_2)$.  In addition, the sum of any values of $\log(z_1)$ and $\log(z_2)$ can be expressed as some value of $\log(z_1z_2)$.

---

Now, suppose $f(z)=\sqrt{z^2-1}=\sqrt{(z-1)(z+1)}$.  By definition, we have

$$\begin{align}
f(z)&=e^{\frac12\log((z-1)(z+1))}\\\\
&=e^{\frac12\left(\log(z-1)+\log(z+1)\right)}\\\\
&=e^{\frac12\sqrt{z-1}}e^{\frac12\sqrt{z+1}}\\\\
\sqrt{z^2-1}&=\sqrt{z-1}\sqrt{z+1}\tag2
\end{align}$$

The equality in $(2)$ is a set equivalence analogous with $(1)$.

---

**EXAMPLE:**

For the example given in the OP, $z=-2$.  We denote by $z_1$ and $z_2$, $z_1=z+1$ and $z_2=z-1$.  Clearly, $z_1=-1$, $z_2=-3$, and $z_1z_2=3$.

The multi-valued term $\log(z_1z_2)$ is given by

$$\log(z_1z_2)=\log(3)=\log(|3|)+i2n\pi\tag 3$$

for any integer $n$.  If we define $\log(z_1)=i\pi$ and $\log(z_2)=\log(|3|)+i\pi$, and if $n=1$ in $(3)$, then $\log(z+1)+\log(z-1)=\log(z^2-1)$.  However, for any other $n$, the equality does not hold.

If we use $(3)$ to calculate $\sqrt{z^2-1}=\sqrt{z_1z_2}$, then we obtain

$$\sqrt{z_1z_2}=\sqrt{3}=\sqrt{|3|}e^{in\pi}\tag 4$$

For $n$ odd, the equality $\sqrt{z_1z_3}=-\sqrt{|3|}=\sqrt{z_1}\sqrt{z_2}$ holds, while for $n$ even, the equality does not hold.

---

Now, let's be more general.  We cut the plane using the principal branch for $\sqrt{z-1}$ and observe that

> $$\sqrt{z-1}=\sqrt{|z-1|}e^{i\text{Arg}(z-1)/2}$$
>
> where $-\pi<\text{Arg}(z)\le \pi$ is the principal argument of $z$.

Similarly, using the principal branch for $\sqrt{z+1}$, we see that

> $$\sqrt{z+1}=\sqrt{|z+1|}e^{i\text{Arg}(z+1)/2}$$
>
> for $-\pi<\text{Arg}(z)\le \pi$.

If we wish to use the principal branch for $\sqrt{z^2-1}$, then the equality $\sqrt{z^2-1}=\sqrt{z-1}\sqrt{z+1}$ does not hold in general.  Rather, the equality holds as follows:

> If $-\pi<\text{Arg}(z-1)+\text{Arg}(z+1)\le \pi$, then $\sqrt{z^2-1}=\sqrt{|z^2-1|}e^{i\text{Arg}(z^2-1)}$.
>
> If $\pi<\text{Arg}(z-1)+\text{Arg}(z+1)\le 2\pi$, then $\sqrt{z^2-1}=\sqrt{|z^2-1|}e^{i\text{Arg}(z^2-1)+2\pi}$
>
> If $-2\pi<\text{Arg}(z-1)+\text{Arg}(z+1)\le -\pi$, then $\sqrt{z^2-1}=\sqrt{|z^2-1|}e^{i\text{Arg}(z^2-1)-2\pi}$

More simply expressed, the equality holds by using the expression $\arg(z^2-1)=\text{Arg}(z-1)+\text{Arg}(z+1)$.

---

Let's use the previous example in which $z=-2$.  We find that $\text{Arg}(z-1)=\text{Arg}(z+1)=\pi$ and $\text{Arg}(z^2-1)=0$.  Indeed, we have

$$\sqrt{z-1}\sqrt{z+1}=\sqrt{z^2-1}$$

when we take $\arg(z^2-1)=\text{Arg}(z^2-1)+2\pi=0+2\pi=2\pi$.

More simply, we have equality with $\arg(z^2-1)=\text{Arg}(z-1)+\text{Arg}(z+1)=2\pi$.

Comment: I think, I got your point. Thank you very much. If I found any difficulty related to this, I will ask.

Comment: Pleased to hear.  And you're welcome.  Feel free to ask anytime.  -Mark