# Imaginary number observation

Tags: complex-numbers

What is the reason for this ?

$ (i^4)^{\frac 12} = 1^{\frac 12} = 1$

$(i^4)^{\frac 12} = {({(i^2)}^2)}^{\frac 12} = i^2 = -1 $

Here, $$ i=\sqrt{-1}$$

Comment: How do you define a square root on complex numbers? Can't just take the positive.

Comment: You need to be very careful with fractional powers of complex numbers.  With the more familiar real numbers, you need to remember that there may be two solutions to $x^2 = y$.  This is also true of the complex numbers with the added complication that there is not such a neat way to pick the primary solution.

Comment: [THIS ANSWER](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2145677/is-logz2-2-logz-if-textlogz-1-z-2-ne-textlogz-1-textlogz/2145780#2145780), [THIS ANSWER](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2253239/choosing-a-branch-of-the-square-root-so-that-this-rewriting-works/2253403#2253403), and [THIS ONE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2251769/what-isare-the-values-of-sqrti-sqrt-i/2251786#2251786) might be helpful to understand the underlying issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The properties of the powers that you are using are [not valid for complex numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation#Powers_of_complex_numbers) if the exponents are not integer.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. The invalidity of the rule $(x^a)b=x^{ab}$ when $x$ is not a positive real and the exponents are not integers needs perpetual repetition.

Answer (score 2):

The reason for that is that every complex number (excepto $0$) has *two* square roots. The notation $a^{\frac12}$ is ambiguous.

Answer (score 0):

Because of the discontinuous nature of the square root function in the complex plane, in general it is not true that $\sqrt{zw}=\sqrt{z}\sqrt{w}$, but if $z,w$ nonnegative real numbers it becomes true. Assuming this rule you can "proof" that 1=-1:
$$-1=ii=\sqrt{-1}\sqrt{-1}=(\neq)\sqrt{(-1)(-1)}=\sqrt{1}=1$$

Comment: Actually, it IS true that $\sqrt{zw}=\sqrt{z}\sqrt{w}$ in the sense of set equivalence.  That is to say that any value of $\sqrt{zw}$ can be expressed as the product of some value of $\sqrt{z}$ and some value of $\sqrt{w}$.  Conversely, the product of any value of $\sqrt{z}$ and any value of $\sqrt{w}$ can be expressed as some value of $\sqrt{zw}$.

Comment: Sure, both of them are sets with same elements.

Comment: And so, under set equivalence, $\sqrt{zw}=\sqrt z\sqrt w$