# Complex integration of $\log(z)/z^2$

Tags: complex-analysis

Show that $$\left| \oint_{|z| = R} \frac{\log z}{z^2}\,dz \right| \leq 2 \sqrt{2} \pi \frac{\log R}{R}, \quad R > e^\pi$$

I tried solving it, but I’m not sure if my methods are correct.

First, let $z =Re^{i \theta},\: 0 \leq \theta \leq 2 \pi$ and $R > e^\pi \Rightarrow dz = iRe^{i \theta} d \theta$.

\begin{align}
\Biggl| \oint_{|z| = R} \frac{\log z}{z^2} dz\, \Biggr| &= \Biggl| \int_0^{2\pi} \frac{\log Re^{i \theta}}{(Re^{i\theta})^2} iRe^{i \theta} d\theta \,\Biggr| = \Biggl| \int_0^{2\pi} \frac{\log R + \log e^{i \theta}}{Re^{i\theta}} d\theta\, \Biggr| \\
&\leq \Biggl| \int_0^{2\pi} \frac{\log R + e^{i\theta} e^{i\theta}}{Re^{i \theta}} d\theta\,\Biggr| \leq\Biggl| \int_0^{2\pi} \frac{\log R \  e^{i\theta}}{R} d\theta \,\Biggr| \leq \Biggl|\int_0^{2\pi} \frac{\log R(1)}{R} d\theta \,\Biggr|  \\
&= \frac{\log R}{R} \theta \biggm|_0^{2\pi} = \frac{\log R}{R}(2\pi) \leq 2 \sqrt{2} \pi \frac{\log R}{R}
\end{align}
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have to specify which branch of logarithm you are using. It is not true that $\log(ab)=\log\, a+\log, b$ so your way of handling $\log(Re^{i\theta})$ is not correct.

Comment: That’s true! Sorry, I’ll fix it accordingly after class. I goofed.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy In fact, $\log(z_1z_2)=\log(z_1)+\log(z_2)$ where the equality is interpreted in terms of set equality.  See [THIS](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2145677/is-logz2-2-logz-if-textlogz-1-z-2-ne-textlogz-1-textlogz/2145780#2145780)

Comment: You also may want to remember that $\left| \oint_{|z| = R} \frac{\log z}{z^2}\,dz \right| \le  \frac{\log(R)}{R^{2}}$

Comment: Correction, I think it should be $\le \frac{| \log (z) |}{R^2}$

Answer (score 2):

The solution is not correct as $\log{e^{i\theta}}$ is just $i\theta$ so the first inequality doesn't make sense, plus you never use the hypothesis about $R > e^\pi$.

The way I would do it is like this; we parameterize the circle as $z =Re^{i \theta},\: -\pi \leq \theta \leq \pi$, so $\log{z} = \log{R} + i\theta$ and then:

$\Biggl| \oint_{|z| = R} \frac{\log z}{z^2} dz\, \Biggr| = \Biggl| \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \frac{\log Re^{i \theta}}{(Re^{i\theta})^2} iRe^{i \theta} d\theta \,\Biggr| = \Biggl| \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \frac{\log R + i\theta}{Re^{i\theta}} d\theta\, \Biggr| \\ \leq \ \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \Biggl|\frac{\log R + i\theta }{Re^{i \theta}}\Biggr| d\theta\, = \frac{1}{R}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}({\log^2{R} + \theta^2})^{\frac{1}{2}} d\theta \leq \frac{1}{R}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}(2{\log^2{R})^{\frac{1}{2}}}d\theta = 
2\sqrt{2} \pi \frac{\log R}{R}$

where we used $R > e^\pi$ to conclude $\log R > |\theta|$ for $-\pi \leq \theta \leq \pi$